# Syntax error near (

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query something and I am not so good with Mysql, so I was wondering if someone can tell me what is the issue here. Here is my table:

```
 create table #transfers (
     sender varchar not null,
     recipient varchar not null,
          date date not null,
          amount integer not null
      );


INSERT INTO #transfers(sender,recipient,date,amount) VALUES ('Smith','Williams','2000-01-01',200);
INSERT INTO #transfers(sender,recipient,date,amount) VALUES ('Smith','Taylor','2002-09-27',1024);
INSERT INTO #transfers(sender,recipient,date,amount) VALUES ('Smith','Johnson','2005-06-26',512);
INSERT INTO #transfers(sender,recipient,date,amount) VALUES ('Williams','Johnson','2010-12-17',100);
INSERT INTO #transfers(sender,recipient,date,amount) VALUES ('Williams','Johnson','2004-03-22',10);
INSERT INTO #transfers(sender,recipient,date,amount) VALUES ('Brown','Johnson','2013-03-20',500);
INSERT INTO #transfers(sender,recipient,date,amount) VALUES ('Johnson','Williams','2007-06-02',400);
INSERT INTO #transfers(sender,recipient,date,amount) VALUES ('Johnson','Williams','2005-06-26',400);
INSERT INTO #transfers(sender,recipient,date,amount) VALUES ('Johnson','Williams','2005-06-26',200);
```

This is the query:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY recipient ORDER BY amount DESC)
  FROM #transfers
)
SELECT recipient
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 3
GROUP BY recipient
HAVING SUM(amount) >= 1024
ORDER BY recipient
```

However I get this error:

near "(": syntax error

Comment: because you are using non mysql syntax (with cte as..) in mysql...

Comment: This looks like an SQL Server query. `CTE`s and `ROW_NUMBER` are not available in MySQL.

Comment: MYSQL doesn't  support `CTE`

Comment: oh ok, then how can I change this query to SQL ? @VigneshKumar

Comment: Your table definition isn't even valid MySQL.  I think you should delete this question.  Try actually creating the table.  Then ask another question, tagged with the correct database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the tables are not that important, the query is the important part, I just gave sample table, let's assume the table is correct

Comment: you sure your table is create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CTEs` and `ROW_NUMBER` are not available in MySQL.

Try with Subquery:

```
SELECT recipient
FROM 
(
     SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
     FROM #transfers t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
)X
WHERE rank <= 3
GROUP BY recipient
HAVING SUM(amount) >= 1024
ORDER BY recipient
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6a48a/1)

Comment: I appreciate your quick response, however:  unrecognized token: ":"

Comment: @secret it's mysql platform right? because i can able to run in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6a48a/1)

Comment: I am so sorry it is SQL

Comment: @secret SQl server means CTE and Row_Number will support and your query right

Comment: but I don't understand why I get the error. I am sorry that my knowledge about databases are limited

Comment: Where did you get such a error. on create or insert or select? @secret

Answer (score 1):

use this create table query

```
create table transfers (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     sender VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     recipient VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          date DATE, 
          amount VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY ( id )
      );
```